# Rails radio button options hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My view:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.recommendation.id}][rating]", '3'%>
```

In my controller, I parse out these values:

```
 input = params[:recommendation_ratings].values
 input.each do |mini_params|
 rating = mini_params[:rating]
 recommendation_id = mini_params[:recommendation_id]
```

Using the rating variable I create a new records in the same controller action:

```
rate = Rating.new(
    :rating => rating,
    :label => rating_label)
```

How can I assign a rating to a rating_label when a new record is created. Example:

```
if rating == 1 rating_label = "Fair"
```

Should I do this in my controller, or can I add the rating_label to my radio_button_tag as another attribute?

**UPDATE:**

I tried a case statement in my controller but get an NoMethodError "Undefined Method Rating"

```
 rating case
      when rating == 1
        rating_label = "Bad"
      when rating == 2
        rating_label = "Fair"
      when rating == 3
        rating_label = "Good"
      else rating == 0
        rating_label = "N/A"
      end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your view code from using `radio_button_tag` to a `fields_for` block:

```
<%= fields_for :recommendation_ratings do |f| %>
  <% f.hidden_field :id, rec.recommendation.id %>
  <% f.radio_button :rating, 3 %>
<% end %>
```

Change your controller code to this:

```
selected_rating = params[:recommendation_ratings]
rating = selected_rating[:rating]
recommendation_id = selected_rating[:id]
```

And add a helper method somewhere as:

```
def rating_label(rating)
  %w{N/A Bad Fair Good}[rating.to_i]
end
```

Now you can make a new `Rating` object like this:

```
rate = Rating.new(
  :rating => rating,
  :label => rating_label(rating))
```